# LibGDX: Viewport using PerspectiveCamera

Tags: libgdx

I want to create a viewport for my scenegraph, that uses a perspective camera. I created a new class that extends the abstract Viewport class.

It only contains the following constructor:

```
public UiViewPort(float worldWidth, float worldHeight) {
    setWorldSize(worldWidth, WorldHeight);
    PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(60, worldWidth, worldHeight);
    camera.position.set(worldWidth / 2f, worldHeight / 2f, (worldHeight / 2f) * (float)Math.tan(Math.PI * 60.0 / 180.0));
    camera.lookAt(worldWidth / 2f, worldHeight / 2f, 0f);
    camera.near = 1f;
    camera.far = 2 * worldWidth;
    camera.update();
    setCamera(camera);
}
```

But I can't see anything from my stage. Interestingly enough I can a least see a part of what I draw, when I change the cameras position to something like: 50, 50, 100.

I don't understand what's wrong. If I'm not using a scenegraph and a stage but only a shaperenderer to draw things, everything works as aspected.

I want to use a perspective camera to zoom into my gui.

Comment: You've got many problems with this approach. Those are not solved via a custom Viewport. Instead maybe have a look at http://pixelscientists.com/blog/posts/3d-ingame-ui-with-scene2dui-in-libgdx

Comment: @noone wow i did not know that it is so easy to create some kind of 3D UI :) But do the normal `Viewport`s (`StretchViewport`, `FitViewport`) stil work with that approach? So can i use a `PerspectiveCamera` as the `Viewport`s `camera`?

Comment: There's no need to create a Custom Viewport. You can just use any common one and do stage.getViewport().setCamera(perspectiveCamera). You will still have problems with Stage, that's why in the blog I linked there's a Stage3D.

Comment: @noone yea my question was about the solution in the linked blog. I understood why you need to create a Stage3D, i was just not sure, if the common `Viewport`s support (or "like") `PerspectiveCamera`s. Thx